# Is "tries it hand" a typo?

Tags: grammaticality

Excerpt the title from [techrepublic.com](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/google-deepmind-ai-tries-it-hand-at-creating-hearthstone-magic-the-gathering-cards/):

> Google Deepmind AI tries **it** hand at creating Hearthstone and Magic: The Gathering cards

The only possible way I can interpret this title is to change *it* to *its*, is it a typo?

Comment: Maybe the AI wrote it...

Comment: As an editor, I would change the word to *its* without a second thought.

Comment: It's a typo that has been corrected elsewhere: https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/4bxp8t/google_deepmind_ai_tries_its_hand_at_creating/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the sentence is grammatically unacceptable. “It” might be a typo.

Answer (score 2):

The OP is right; the use of 'it' is a typo.

The correct phrase is "try your hand at (doing) something". 'Your" in the phrase is a possessive adjective.

So you should use the possessive adjective 'its' instead of the subject pronoun 'it'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's plainly a mistake.

Replacing *it* with *its* makes the sentence sensical.

But is *sensical* a word?

> Well, of course it’s a word. What a silly question. They use it, you understand it. No act of parliament or congress is required, nor any lexicographer’s imprimatur.

[Sesquiotica](https://sesquiotic.wordpress.com/2013/01/10/sensical/)

Answer (score 0):

> "Google Deepmind AI tries it hand at creating Hearthstone and Magic: The Gathering cards"
>
> The only possible way I can interpret this title is to change it to its, is it a typo?

It is possible that it is a typo, but there is **no evidence** to support that. Throughout the webpage the spelling and usage of "it", "its", and "it's" is correct; if one were to presume that was yet another example of correct spelling and usage then it's a matter of capitalization and not spelling.

Compare the other example of the same spelling and usage at the end of the webpage, the author often uses the abbreviation "**IT**" to refer to Information Technology. The author abbreviated Artificial Intelligence, why not abbreviate Information Technology too?

Read the ***whole*** article, beginning to end:

> "Google Deepmind AI tries **[IT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_technology)** hand at creating Hearthstone and Magic: The Gathering cards
>
> ...
>
> By Nick Heath
>
> Nick Heath is chief reporter for TechRepublic. He writes about the technology that **[IT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_technology)** decision makers need to know about, and the latest happenings in the European tech scene.".

**The title reads:**

**Google Deepmind Artificial Intelligence tries Information Technology hand at creating Hearthstone and Magic: The Gathering cards**

References:

- CapitalizeMyTitle - [Title Capitalization Rules by Style](https://capitalizemytitle.com/)
- Purdue Online Writing Lab - [Associated Press Style](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/subject_specific_writing/journalism_and_journalistic_writing/ap_style.html)
- [2019 AP Stylebook](https://www.apstylebook.com/)

[Terse](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/terse) and abbreviated is a common style for headlines, it would be a great failing to have a spelling error in the title. It's not *better* to have a capitalization error in the title either, best to have neither problem. Only the author knows for certain but if I had to guess between the two I'd give them the benefit of the doubt and also keep in mind the subject under discussion.